# I have my component folder inside the src folder. I want to import the file MyApp. What to do?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, jsx

This is the error i get. I need an specifik answer so i can move on. I have been searching for hours for a solution. 
**which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.**

Comment: share your import code

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out myself. The import code was written without capital R.